# Why nothing happens after crontab?

Tags: linux, crontab

After executing fllowing command cursor skips to new line and nothing happens

```
user@machine:~$ sudo crontab
```

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`crontab` is an interactive command. If you type the command without any option it assumes that you type in your crontab specification interactive. Example:

```
user@machine:~$ crontab
0/15 * * * * /usr/bin/ls
```

After that you can press CTRL+D and crontab is trying to install your typed in configuration as crontab for that user. It overwrites your actual crontab so be careful.

Now a bit clarification for crontab usage:
`crontab -e` is for crontab editing, if you run this command for the first time and the variables $VISUAL and/or $EDITOR are not set you will be asked whats you're favourite editor and the next time the crontab will be edited with this editor.

with `vi <file>` you can make your crontab configuration and with `crontab <file>` you can install the crontab to the system.

All of this commands are executed in the user context. If you run these commands preceding with `sudo` they will be executed as root. You can also install and/or edit crontabs for other users with `sudo crontab -e -u <username>`.

Comment: And how to edit whole file? Once I could `vim` a file with list of cronjobs save it and it was done

Comment: To edit use `crontab -e`. It will use the editor as specified in $VISUAL or in $EDITOR (which can be vi[m])

Comment: If I do `sudo crontab -e` tasks will be done as user or as root?

Comment: `crontab -e` is the right way. If you start it for the first time you will be asked what your favourite editor is. You could also make a new file with `vim` and then install it with `crontab <filename>`

Comment: yes, `sudo crontab -e` edits the crontab of root. You can also do `sudo crontab -e -u <other user>` to edit crontabs of other users.